# Move View Behind Keyboard When textfield selected

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, swift2

Recently I used this to Move View Behind Keyboard When textfield is selected

http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/move-view-behind-keyboard-ios8-swift

What if I need to move view only for some inputs, others are near top and don't need it? I tries the following code but no success in that.

```
var searcher

    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
       if (searcher.tag == 1){
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            if let keyboardSize =  (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
                kbHeight = keyboardSize.height
                self.animateTextField(true)
            }
        }
}
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [AutoKeyboardScrollView](https://github.com/honghaoz/AutoKeyboardScrollView) library instead of adding code manually. This library already does what you need with the expected behaviour.

As seen on the project's readme:

[image]

Comment: how do i install it !?

Comment: @AhmedSafadi you may find installation instructions on the repository's readme file.

Comment: the problem is that i should use constant and i don't want to do that

Answer (score 0):

Another great library for this is IQKeyboardManager. https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Simple to use and will do this globally for your entire app. Easy configuration and it adds previous, next and done functionality

If you're using cocoapods, just add

```
pod 'IQKeyboardManager-Swift'
```

Check out the docs on the GitHub page for the config options

Comment: it's too big for my project :(